# CAS Single Sign Out ticket not valid

Tags: java, spring, cas, shiro

I triggered CAS Single Sign Out event by visit `https://xx/cas-server/logout?service=myservice`, and CAS POST a request to `myservice`(http://test.ogg:8080/cas) with the body：

`<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="LR-329-TxwPlscwOydLQH0JD0R2AKmOr4ew5FdiKN2" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-07-15T08:21:38Z"><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">@NOT_USED@</saml:NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>ST-329-lNWcDWJIW0Ve7ij9gsNG-cas</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>`

I have customised logout logic, so used the ticket in `<samlp:SessionIndex>ST-329-lNWcDWJIW0Ve7ij9gsNG-cas</samlp:SessionIndex>` to call `https://xx/cas-server/validateService？service=myservice&ticket=ST-329-lNWcDWJIW0Ve7ij9gsNG-cas`, but CAS report ticket invalid：

`<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationFailure code='INVALID_TICKET'>
        Ticket &#039;ST-329-lNWcDWJIW0Ve7ij9gsNG-cas&#039; not recognized
    </cas:authenticationFailure>`

Here is the log from CAS server:

```
2016-07-15 08:21:38,334 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.SamlCompliantLogoutMessageCreator.create(SamlCompliantLogoutMessageCreator.java:53)] - Generated logout message: [<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="LR-328-qwK2GgGVhRlRtu9QtebIoXIo30iwd4dWWwu" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-07-15T08:21:38Z"><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">@NOT_USED@</saml:NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>ST-329-lNWcDWJIW0Ve7ij9gsNG-cas</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>]

2016-07-15 08:21:38,334 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl.performBackChannelLogout(LogoutManagerImpl.java:143)] - Sending logout request for: [http://test.ogg:8080/cas]

2016-07-15 08:21:38,334 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.util.SimpleHttpClient$MessageSender.call(SimpleHttpClient.java:297)] - Attempting to access http://test.ogg:8080/cas

2016-07-15 08:21:38,371 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.AbstractArgumentExtractor.extractService(AbstractArgumentExtractor.java:45)] - Extractor generated service for: http://test.ogg:8080/cas

2016-07-15 08:21:38,372 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry.getTicket(DefaultTicketRegistry.java:80)] - Attempting to retrieve ticket [ST-329-lNWcDWJIW0Ve7ij9gsNG-cas]

2016-07-15 08:21:38,372 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.validateServiceTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:413)] - ServiceTicket [ST-329-lNWcDWJIW0Ve7ij9gsNG-cas] does not exist.
```

It seems the ticket was expired in 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

When you have logged out, you have logged out. There is nothing further for you to do. Everything is gone. You can't validate something that is destroyed.